# Add confirmation to Yii Menu items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, cmenu

I have a menu like this in my Yii application:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),

            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Logout('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest, ))


        ),
    )); ?>
```

How can I add javascript or Jquery confirmation box to my last menu link? I mean when users click on Logout, javascript box shown and if user click on Ok then it logouts otherwise nothing happen.

Comment: just check by adding `array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?')`

Comment: I add this: array('label'=>'Home('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest,array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?') )   and nothing happen, even when I check with FireBug nothing added to related anchor tag. Could you tell me exactly where should I add it?

Answer (score 2):

I found it, here is the answer:

```
array(
'label'=>'خروج ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 
'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 
'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest,
'linkOptions' => array('onclick'=>'return confirm("آیا برای خروج از سایت اطمینان دارید؟")') 
)
```